# Health insurance for expats in France

Tags: france, health-insurance

I posted [earlier](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12987/language-restrictions-in-france/12994#12994) asking about the importance of the French language and basic visa requirements. I got great answers and so I ask here again.

I'll be 29 years old this year and will start a master's course in France this year. I understand that students/people over 28 years of age are NOT covered by the state-provided health insurance and must opt for a private health insurance. The visa requirements state that I have to provide a travel insurance covering at least 3 months and I have been told by the University representative that the University will provide assistance of all kinds. My questions, hence:

1. What is the PUMA? I have [read](https://www.expatica.com/fr/healthcare/Guide-to-health-insurance-in-France_108848.html) about it but I'm not very clear about the eligibility and what will be covered.
2. If I'm not eligible for "national health insurance", what options do I have? Can I get a list of private health insurance and prices?
3. Is it advisable to opt for a health insurance from my country covering, let's say 2 years? Given that the insurance company has a presence in France, will such an insurance hold?
4. Does one need a specific medical certificate or are there any medical processes/vaccinations required for French visa? I do not suffer from any ailment and have been vaccinated.

I'm from India and will be starting in September 2018.

Comment: 30 year old PhD student in France here. You're covered by the state health insurance, you just can't get the university's mutuelle (top up insurance). Same with me. I don't have a mutuelle and haven't for 3 years. You will pay about half the price of whatever out of pocket. A visit to the GP is 29 euros / 2, and my prescriptions every month are about 3 euros or so. Just to give you some idea of what it's like to not have a mutuelle.

Comment: There are (at least) two kinds of state provided health insurance: one specific for students, and another for the general adult population (managed by the CPAM). The 28 age limit is related to whether you use the former or the latter. The latter is likely going to be slightly more bureaucratic (e.g. you have to prove your income is less than 720€/month, or something like that), but you'll still have access to it, following some procedures. However I'll let someone more knowledgeable about the details answer it.